# How to Pass multidimensional array to API using laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, api

I am fetching data from two tables using join, however, I want my result to return a multi-dimensional array , i.e.

**FRUITS**

- Apple
- Mango
- Orange

**Animal**

- Dog
- Cat
- Cow

**Country**

- Germany
- UK
- USA

So, that is what I want it to return, see my code below

```
 Route::get('all-category', function(){

$category = DB::table('directory_companies')
             ->join('categories','directory_companies.categories_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->select('categories.name', 'directory_companies.*') 
             ->get();
return response()->json($category);
```

How do I return it to display like the list above in multidimensional array, I am using Laravel to build the API

Comment: You should use the laravel relationship it will be a lot easier https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [eloquent resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources) for displaying any structure you want for api.

**Create resource and Reourse Collection**

```
php artisan make:resource directory_companies
php artisan make:resource directory_companies_collection --collection
```

```
$category = DB::table('directory_companies')
             ->join('categories','directory_companies.categories_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->select('categories.name', 'directory_companies.*') 
             ->get();

return response()
    ->json(new directory_companies_collection(new directory_companies($category)));
```

And in your **directory_companies** resource:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            // Any structure of data you want to present
        ];
    }
```